# Developing and testing website and AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, iis-express

I am developing an Intranet application that uses AD for Windows authentication and for employee and organization information. The application is in c#, .NET MVC4. I develop using IIS Express and SQL Server Express. The employees are referenced by the principal's Guid, for example the creator of a record will be referenced as AuthorId which then contains a string representing the Guid that comes from AD. Different users see different views based on their group membership, for example with the same url admins can edit categories in an editor view but users can only see the category in a display view.

Questions:
- Without unnecessarily accessing the domain AD, how can I test the code that queries AD?
- How do I best assume different user access without changing the domain AD?

I was thinking of using ADAM for the testing. But then my questions are:
- how and what should I configure to authenticate using this local ADAM server?
- can the ADAM installation be on my second development machine or should it be local?
- what does a connection string look like when I install that ADAM server on my second development machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of reading and some trying, I found out the following:

No, you cannot test authentication (that is testing multiple user accounts and the results on your code) without either adding fake users to your domain or setting up a specific domain for the testing purpose.

But for testing the role system in your code you can unit test your MVC/API controller. For that purpose you have to mock the request context.

MVC: http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2009/05/23/aspnet-mvc-testing-a-custom-authorize-filters/

API: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/358709/

The point in both is that you cannot mock the whole principal (especially the Guid), but you can fake the response to a request for the roles which you can then use in your test.

Using roles in you application, you can assign one of the groups you are in to the role you want to test and off you go. For the basis of a role system:

http://geekswithblogs.net/tyarmer/archive/2010/02/25/strongly-typed-roles-in-mvc-with-authorize-attribute.aspx

Setting up a local LDAP server for this kind of testing is useless and too much work.